# How to initialize services in a chain constructor aproach

Tags: c#, class, dependency-injection, constructor, chaining

I have the following Main class that takes a dataStore as a constructor parameter for Foo class.

In the Main class I want to pass to Foo only one constructor, 'dataStore', but in the Foo constructor class I want to initialize besides dataStore also a couple of other services.

```
public class Main
{
    private DataStore dataStore = new DataStore();

    public Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo(dataStore);
        foo.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I've try this approach with chaining the Foo constructors, but only the dataStore is initialized,
_serviceOne and _serviceTwo are null in this case (because I'm passing null in the construnctor chaining, and the second construnctor is never called).

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly DataStore _dataStore;
    private readonly IServiceOne _serviceOne;
    private readonly IServiceTwo _serviceTwo;


    public Foo(DataStore dataStore) : this(null, null)
    {
        _dataStore = dataStore;
    }

    public Foo(IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo)
    {
        _serviceOne = serviceOne;
        _serviceTwo = serviceTwo;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

If I try to pass all the data to only one Foo constructor, I need to pass _dataStore , _serviceOne and _serviceTwo as arguments for Foo as well in the Main classs and I don't what this.

```
    public Foo(DataStore dataStore, IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo)
    {
        _dataStore = dataStore;
        _serviceOne = serviceOne;
        _serviceTwo = serviceTwo;
    }
```

Is there a way to pass only dataStore as argument in Main class, and also to initialize all the fields(_dataStore,_serviceOne,_serviceTwo) in Foo constructor class?

Esentially I what to pass to Foo only the _dataStore and to instantiate the rest of the services in the Foo class itself:

```
var foo = new Foo(dataStore);
```

Comment: Is there any scenario where any of these - `_dataStore`, `_serviceOne`, or `_serviceTwo` - should be null? That would be weird. If nothing is passed to the constructor, do you intend for `Foo` to create an instance of some class and assign it to the field?

Comment: Esentially I what to pass to Foo only the _dataStore
```
var foo = new Foo(dataStore);
```
and to instantiate the rest of the services in the Foo class itself

Comment: Before you start typing - I recommend editing the question, not putting it in a comment. It's best if the question is clear without having to read through the comments.

Comment: "and I don't what this." Can you elaborate on why it is you don't want the `Main` to supply those dependencies to `Foo`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to do this.  You can just initialize the IServiceOne, IServiceTwo references in the `Foo(DataStore)` constructor.  But if you really need to, it definitely works, here is a working dotnetfiddle adapted from your code:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2FDjix

```
using System;

public class DataStore {}

public interface IServiceOne {}
public interface IServiceTwo {}

public class ServiceOne : IServiceOne {}
public class ServiceTwo : IServiceTwo {}

public class Program
{
        private static DataStore dataStore = new DataStore();
 
        public static void Main()
        {
            var foo = new Foo(dataStore);
            foo.DoSomething();
       }
}

public class Foo
{
    private readonly DataStore _dataStore;
    private readonly IServiceOne _serviceOne;
    private readonly IServiceTwo _serviceTwo;


    public Foo(DataStore dataStore) : this(null, null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo 1st construcor");
        _dataStore = dataStore;
    }

    public Foo(IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo 2nd constructor");
        _serviceOne = serviceOne;
        _serviceTwo = serviceTwo;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Output:

> Foo 2nd constructor

> Foo 1st construcor

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is

- You'll always pass a `DataStore` to the constructor and the class will use that.
- You may or may not want to pass `IServiceOne` or `IServiceTwo`. If you don't pass them, them class will provide its own implementation

...there are a few ways to do that. Here's one.

```cs
public Foo(DataStore dataStore) : this(dataStore, null, null)
{
}

public Foo(DataStore dataStore, IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo)
{
    _dataStore = dataStore;
    _serviceOne = serviceOne ?? new SomeImplementationOne();
    _serviceTwo = serviceTwo ?? new SomeImplementationTwo();
}
```

You might wonder - why even have the first constructor at all if you can just call the second one and pass nulls for `serviceOne` and `serviceTwo`?

The answer is that you could do that. Having two constructors just makes it a little bit clearer that there are choices. If all you had was the second constructor, someone might not know that they had the option of passing `null` and letting the class provide its own implementation.

Even then, it's a little confusing because it might not be obvious to the caller that if they pass null, the class will replace the null with something else.

Here's another option:

```cs
public Foo(DataStore dataStore)
{
    _dataStore = dataStore ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataStore));
    _serviceOne = new SomeImplementationOne();
    _serviceTwo = new SomeImplementationTwo();
}

public Foo(DataStore dataStore, IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo)
{
    _dataStore = dataStore ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataStore));
    _serviceOne = serviceOne ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceOne));
    _serviceTwo = serviceTwo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceTwo));
}
```

This keeps the constructors separate. One uses the `dataStore` argument and supplies the other two. The second constructor requires that you pass all three.

It might not be worth overthinking. It's good to imagine someone else using the class later and thinking about which will make it the most obvious.